# login fails with error utmp entry not found | exec(bin/login)

Tags: c, authentication, exec, posix

Following code fails:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    execlp("/bin/login", "/bin/login", (char *)NULL);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

with the following error:
**No utmp entry.  You must exec "login" from the lowest level "sh"**

Comment: What are you really trying to do? What is the problem you need to solve by using `/bin/login`?

Comment: It's an exercise in the book TheLinuxProgrammingInterface
64-5. Implement client and server programs to provide a simple telnet-style remote login facility. Design the server to handle clients concurrently (Section 60.1). Figure 64-3 shows the setup that needs to be established for each client login. What isn’t shown in that diagram is the parent server process, which handles incoming socket connections from clients and creates a server child to handle each connection.

Comment: Note that all of the work of authenticating the user and starting a login shell can be dealt with in each server child by having the (grand)child created by ptyFork() go on to exec login(1).

Comment: It only fails here, the rest is done.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it works if i am root (EUID = 0)